# complex contour integral $\frac{1}{3+2\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

So I'm asked to do $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{3+2\sin(x)}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$ using contour integrals.

Can somebody please help me? I was thinking, maybe by using residues or something?

Comment: Although this doesn't evolve contour integrals, you can make the substitution t=tan(x/2) and then integrate normally

Answer (score 4):

A useful initial manipulation is to exploit symmetry:
$$ I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{3+2\sin(x)} = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{6\,dx}{9-4\sin^2(x)} = 12\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{dx}{9-4\cos^2(x)} $$
Then by setting $x=\arctan t$ we get:
$$ I = 12 \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{9(1+t^2)-4} = 6\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{9t^2+5} $$
At last, by exploiting the residue theorem:
$$ I = 12\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{9t^2+5},t=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{3}i\right) = \color{blue}{\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{5}}}.$$
Obviously $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{9t^2+5}$ can be computed by real techniques only, if needed. 
Additionally, the final outcome can be deduced from the properties of the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel), too.

Comment: I'm very curious in how you came up with that first symmetry... Seems to be a substitution of some sorts, but I cant figure out what substitution to use off the top of my head

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Split the integral, exploit the oddness of the sine, and combine.

Comment: @Dr.MV Here is the easiest proof I could make... $$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{3+2\sin(x)}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{3+2\sin(x)}+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{3+2\sin(x)}$$
$x\to x-\pi$ and $\sin(x-\pi) = -\sin(x)$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{dx}{3+2\sin(x)}+\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{3-2\sin(x)}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{6\,dx}{(3-2\sin x)(3+2\sin x)}$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{6\,dx}{9-4\sin^2(x)}$$
I just can't figure out how to apply the oddness of sine like you recommend (except in that one substitution), and so the proof seems very out there and not intuitive. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Your proof is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute

$$z=e^{ix}\implies dz=izdx\;,\;\;\sin x=\frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})=\frac1{2i}\left(z-z^{-1}\right)=\frac{z^2-1}{2iz}\implies$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{iz}\cdot\frac1{3+2\frac{z^2-1}{2iz}}=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{z^2+3iz-1}=$$

$$=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac1{\left(z-\frac{3+\sqrt5}2i\right)\left(z-\frac{3-\sqrt5}2i\right)}=\left.2\pi i\left(\frac1{z-\frac{3+\sqrt5}2i}\right)\right|_{z=\frac{3-\sqrt5}2i}=\frac2{\sqrt5}\pi$$

Comment: So this is integration by substitution on a contour integral?

Comment: @GFauxPas In fact this is a way to change a real integral into a complex one, and sometimes it works out pretty nicely.

Comment: what happened to the negative sign you get on the denominator when evaluating at z, on the last line ?